# Flutter Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 4)

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I try to receive data from MySQL database. To do this I connect to .php file on server from my app. But I see exception in Android studio.

Error description:

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 4)
E/flutter (13513): "1""Mike""Deon""404""2""9577813""2""...
E/flutter (13513):    ^
```

PHP file code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'DatabaseName')
 or die("Error" . mysqli_error($link)); 
//echo 'DB Connection.....OK!<br>';

$query ="SELECT * FROM Store";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));



if($result)
{
     $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


       for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {


        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);


            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 6 ; ++$j) echo json_encode($row[$j],JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    }
    echo "</table>";

   mysqli_free_result($result);
}

?>
```

Dart code in app:
....

```
Future getData() async {
  var url = 'https://mywebserver/data.php';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data.toString());
}

@override
void initState() {
  getData();
}
```

Comment: print the `response.body` before the jsonDecode, it looks like is not a json data

Comment: Thanks, for answer, I just print:  print(response.body.toString()); And Error not showing!

Comment: update your question with that content to check the data received

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for answer to diegoveloper! 
I just change: print(response.body.toString()); And error not showing!